# Python 2.7 exporting data in a .csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have this piece of code that works at gathering data from a serial port connected machine, the data is then reordered.
I can successfully print my data at the end : `print pigment_data`

However I don't get how to **export** this data to a `.csv` file.

Is there any straightforward way to do this?

Thank you very much,

Adrien

```
import serial  # requires pyserial library
import csv

ser  = serial.Serial(0)
data = []

while True:
    name = raw_input("Pigment name [DONE to finish]: ")
    if name == "DONE":
        break

    pigment_data = []
    first = True
    main_spect = []

    while True:
        line = ser.readline()
        if first:
            print "  Data incoming..."
            first = False
        split = line.split()
        if 10 <= len(split):
            try:
                wavelength = int(split[0])
                measurements = [float(split[i]) for i in [2,4,6,8,10]]
                pigment_data.append({"wavelength": wavelength,
                                     "measurements": measurements})
                main_spect.append(measurements[2])
            except ValueError:
                pass    # handles the table heading
        if line[:3] == "110":
            break
    data.append({"name": name,
                 "data": pigment_data})
    print "  Data gathered."
    print pigment_data

    # here's the problem:
    with open('spectral_data.csv', 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(pigment_data)
```

Comment: You say "here's the problem", but *what* is? Errors (provide traceback)? Unexpected output (provide inputs, outputs, expected outputs)? For one thing you don't actually *pass* anything to `writerows()`

Comment: right, sorry, my mistake (see edit)

Comment: You have only addressed the last point I made, what about the other questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gathered a list of dictionaries, use [`csv.DictWriter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) here instead to make this easier:

```
with open('spectral_data.csv', 'ab') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ('name', 'data'))
    writer.writerow(data[-1])
```

This opens the file in append-mode as well, since you are opening the file once every loop. I used `data[-1]` here because that's the last entry you added in the loop.

You probably want to move the creation of the `writer` object *out* of your loop:

```
with open('spectral_data.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ('name', 'data'))

    while True:
        name = raw_input("Pigment name [DONE to finish]: ")
        # ....

        print pigment_data

        writer.writerow(data[-1])
```

which writes the newest entry you gathered to the CSV file as you gather it.

Last but not least, you can also write the whole `data` list in one go after the outer `while True:` is done:

```
data = []

while True:
    name = raw_input("Pigment name [DONE to finish]: ")
    # ....

with open('spectral_data.csv', 'ab') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ('name', 'data'))
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

from `csv.writer`'s help:

```
writer(...)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(fileobj [, dialect='excel']
                                [optional keyword args])
        for row in sequence:
            csv_writer.writerow(row)

        [or]

        csv_writer = csv.writer(fileobj [, dialect='excel']
                                [optional keyword args])
        csv_writer.writerows(rows)

    The "fileobj" argument can be any object that supports the file API.
```

so basically you want:

```
with open('spectral_data.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in pigment_data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```